# Which photo websites have iPad support for editing and ordering prints, cards and books?

Tags: photos, printing, image-editing, mobileme, ipad

I've tried the *Shutterfly* iPad app, which allows uploading photos, but doesn't support any other functionality available on the website. And I can't edit photos or design cards and books from the Mobile Safari browswer on the iPad, presumably because those features use *Flash*.

Are there any other photo websites that provide either a full-featured iPad app (that includes creating cards and books and ordering prints) or an iPad or iPhone app that allows uploading photos and a website that allows one to create cards and books and order prints in Mobile Safari?

Note: I download photos directly from my camera to the iPad, so I'm trying to figure out how to avoid any need for a PC.

**Update:** Someone (on [vark.com](http://vark.com/t/SZwNAG)) recommended Apple's [MobileMe](http://me.com).  But the official [features list](http://www.apple.com/mobileme/features/gallery.html) doesn't show that it supports editing photos and ordering prints, cards, and books.  Does anyone have experience with MobileMe?

Answer (score 1):

- Adobe apps which fit your need according to editing photos or graphic designing.

  https://www.adobe.com/creativecloud/catalog/mobile.html
- Canva online editor and app. I haven't used it, but have seen people.

  https://www.canva.com

Answer (score -2):

When using an iPad you will have to use an app for anything complex. Mobile browsers aren't built to deliver the desktop experience to mobile devices because they don't function like desktop and laptop computers.

Look for apps that you can use to edit photos, then an app to create cards, then an app to order prints. There maybe a few apps that do all three, but you will be limited in one way or the other regardless of which apps you choose.

Comment: I'll upvote and accept this answer if you modify it to list specific apps.